# Break Pressure Plate Bukkit

Tags: java, api, minecraft, bukkit

**How do I replace a pressure plate with another block?**

If I just do (bl represents the pressure plate):

```
bl.setType(Material.BEACON)
```

The pressure plate stays. If I check it by writing:

```
System.out.println(bl.getType())
```

it says

```
BEACON
```

but in the world it's a pressure plate...

More code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onInteract(EntityInteractEvent ev) {
    if(ev.getEntityType().equals(EntityType.DROPPED_ITEM)) {
        if(ev.getBlock().getType().equals(Material.WOOD_PLATE)) {
            if(ev.getBlock().hasMetadata("luckywell")) {
                System.out.println(ev.getBlock().getType());
                ev.getBlock().setType(Material.AIR);
                System.out.println(ev.getBlock().getType());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints

```
PRESSURE_PLATE
AIR
```

So everything is fine with the code, it just doesn't replace the block.

Comment: Are you sure you selected the right block? One of the coordinates might be off. Try replacing it by /setblock x y z [block] ingame to check it

Comment: Nope @AscendedKitten Coords are fine...

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the right block? This seems to work

Comment: Could you show us more code, so we can try to understand better what you're doing?

Comment: @Kerooker posted code below

Comment: @Kerooker if I replace the block at the coords the block has, it replaces the actual ingame block

Comment: I'm not sure what causes this, but try using a small 'hacky' sollution: Put your `setType` in a `ScheduledTask` [Check This to understand more of scheduling](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bukkit/5436/scheduler-programming#t=201701152123161450222)

Comment: @Kerooker that's not a "hacky" solution in any way. That's the point of scheduling, the point of `invokeLater` in Swing, etc.

Comment: @1blustone It's a kind of a hacky solution due to the fact that SetType should work on it's own for any block, and shouldn't be scheduled as a task, so it's a workaround

Comment: First things, first, what version of Bukkit/Spigot are you running? And second, is it possible that you are trying this near spawn which could be protected (see your config)?

Comment: Third, are you using any other plugins while you are testing this? The above code should work, though I would recommend using `BlockState` to make changes since the block could be changed by other processes or players.

Comment: Try to force unload and load the chunk again